# Work and energy related

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy, work

*No friction*
In case of no friction work done will be equal to total $F$ applied? When we multiply $F$ and $s$, we are basically calculating Total Force applied, right? So does that mean total $F$ applied will be equal to the amount of energy transferred?

Answer (score 4):

Force and work are two different concepts, but they are related. So when force is multiplied by displacement, you get the amount of energy an object has to use in order to push an object or pull an object over a certain amount of distance.

Force on the other hand is the actual push or pull that causes the object to move in the first place, whereas work can be treated like the "cost" of exerting that force over a long distance.

An analogy can be where a person has 100 dollars, and they have the ability to spend it at $20 at each shop that is separated by one meter. In this case the force would be analogous to the ability for a person to spend. In this same analogy, work would be the total amount of money spent by using up that ability however many times. So say the person went 3 meters, and used their max spending ability 3 times, then they spent 60 dollars. This is analogous to work. Of course, there is also a limit which is usually the total amount of energy which can be analogous to the amount of total money the person has.

Now applying this same logic to a problem, lets say there is a motor that has a 100 joules (newtons$\times$meters) stored in its battery. The motor has the ability of pushing the block with a force of 20 Newtons. This is its maximum ability. Now this is just an ability but for it to actually move the object somewhere, energy has to be exerted, and so if it moves say 3 meters, then the total energy used is 60 joules.

Answer (score 0):

If you apply a force $F$ over a distance $x$, you did work equal to:

$$ W = Fx $$

That energy went somewhere, and wether that's kinetic energy, fictional losses, gravitational radiation, or whatever... does not matter.

You put in the $W$.